# How to develop oauth2 for google plus only in python?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-plus

My python application is develop for google plus api but I have to develop my own oauth2 in python without use of Third Party Tools.

Only google plus oauth2 for **public post** **get, list, search** and also **people details get**.

Access token and refresh token how get and check in Oauth2.

Answer (score 1):

Install requests and requests_oathlib with pip.

Here's example code for using requests_oauthlib:

```
CLIENT_KEY = '...'
CLIENT_SECRET = '...'
RESOURCE_OWNER_KEY = '...'
RESOURCE_OWNER_SECRET = '...'

auth = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1(CLIENT_KEY,
                                CLIENT_SECRET,
                                RESOURCE_OWNER_KEY,
                                RESOURCE_OWNER_SECRET,
                                signature_type='auth_header')

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = auth

s.post(...)
```

Comment: this thing develop without use of any third party tools...